# Magento discount for various shopping cart price rules

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

I am working on magento 1.9. I need a way to apply discount for a particular category say 'CAT A'.

1. Buy 1 Product from CAT A at 30% discount
2. Buy 2 Products from CAT A at 40% discount
3. Buy 3 or more Products from CAT A at 50% discount

Other category products can be accompanied but the discount should be applied only to CAT A.

Comment: If I'd buy 3 x Prod X, then I also get 50% discount? Or is it 3 different products only (1 x Prod X, 1 x Prod Y and 1 x Prod Z)?

Comment: You will get 50% if you get 3x Prod X too

Answer (score 0):

I assume you do specific rules for each of them as seen in the pictures below[image: Condition]

[image]

And then for the 40 percent just say the quantity is two (instead of 1 in the first picture) and so on for the 3rd rule. I hope its clear :-)

[image]